# How to configure and use serverless offline in macOS?

Tags: npm, package.json, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I am trying to use the serverless-offline library, using the serverless framework,
I have the serverless.yaml file properly configured, with the -

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

added to it.

**Following is my package.json -**

```
{
  "name": "serverless-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda APIs for Test Module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/serverless offline -s dev",
    "debug": "export SLS_DEBUG=* && node --debug ./node_modules/.bin/serverless offline -s dev"
  },
  "author": "Aniruddha",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.447.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "4.9.4"
  }
}
```

**I used the following command to install the packages -**

```
npm i
```

also ran -

```
npm i dev
```

And ran `sls offline` and `serverless offline`
to run the offline mode.

**But I am getting the following error -**

```
bash: sls: command not found
```

and

```
bash: serveless: command not found
```

**I checked the npm logs and found this -**

```
112 error code EBADPLATFORM
113 error notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.6: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
114 error notsup Valid OS:    linux
114 error notsup Valid Arch:  any
114 error notsup Actual OS:   darwin
114 error notsup Actual Arch: x64
115 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I could use the serverless-offline fine on ubuntu,
But unable to so do on Mac,
Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `serverless offline` plugin but with the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) instead: it is not installed, thus you get

> sls (or serverless) command not found

Just run `npm install serverless -g`. Keep in mind that depending how you have set up `npm` you may need `sudo` permissions to install packages globally.

Comment: I am trying to install serverless-offline plugin on mac, how do I verify the installation?